# self.traitCollection is not filled in a child UIViewController's viewDidLoad

Tags: ios8, autolayout, constraints, traits, size-classes

I'm using a ready-to-use library with `UIViewController` that add my
`UIViewController` as a child controller.
In the `viewDidLoad` of my controller the `self.traitCollection` is not ready.
Why can that be? I understand that my child controller might not be ready but I
don't know why exactly this happens.
In a simple one view project the `self.traitCollection` is filled in with
correct values in `viewDidLoad`.

I'm trying to learn the autolayout system together with size classes and wanted
to set autolayout constraints in the `viewDidLoad` according to traits.

Comment: What ready-to-use library are you using?

Comment: @joern MMDrawerController https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController